# function returning NaN

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>

  function myfunction()
  {
     var year = prompt("enter your birth year");
     Number(year);
     document.getElementById('year').innerHTML = year;

     myage();
  }

  function myage(year)
  {
    var res;
    res = 2016 - year;
    document.getElementById("age").innerHTML = res;
  }
 </script>
 <p id="year"><h1>YEAR</h1></p>
 <p id="age"><h2>your age is=</h2></p>
 <button onclick="myfunction()">click to login</button>
```

Though I have used the function `Number()` still `myage()` results in `NaN`.
(I am a beginner so please forgive me for my lack of knowledge.)

Comment: You're not passing anything to the `myage` function, and JS has lexical scoping, so it's not going to see your `var year`. Do `myage(year)` instead.

Comment: i did myage(year).please see the code again.

Comment: `Number` doesn't mutate the original variable.

Comment: No, when you're *calling* `myage`, pass it year. In other words, change the last line of the `myfunction` from `myage();` to `myage(year);`

Comment: This has nothing to do with HTML.

Comment: @ScottHunter There is HTML in the question, and the JS is getting DOM elements. How does it not have anything to do with HTML?

Comment: The question is about Javascript functions.  The code is about computing one's age; are you suggesting it should be so tagged as well?

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass the value to your function myage

```
 myage(year);
```

**updated snippet**

```js
 function myfunction()
 { 
   var year=prompt("enter your birth year");
   document.getElementById('year').nextSibling.innerHTML = "Year Of Birth = " +year;
   
   myage(year);
 }
function myage(year)
{
  var res;
  res=2016-year;
  document.getElementById('age').nextSibling.innerHTML = "your age is =" + res;
  
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>
<p id="year"><h1></h1></p>
<p id="age"><h2></h2></p>
<button onclick="myfunction()">click to login</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you run the code snippet? i have modified the code to print the values in front of the labels.

Comment: is this working as you expected? Let me know in case you were looking for something else.

Comment: sir your code is printing year=19 and your age is=1997 @deep

Comment: could you recheck once if you are updating the same document element as i am doing here. in the SO snippet i can see this result YEAR = 1997

your age is=19

Comment: @KaushaniRC : did it work for you ?? I have done few modification in the snippet above to change the label at run time.You can keep you initial h1 tag  blank to just show the button at the page load.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested earlier, you have to pass the age as a parameter to the myage function.

**Another way of doing this**:
You can set the default value of year parameter. In this way you can escape sending it via a parameter. [Default Parameter Value MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) might be a good read.So this function can take hardcoded values from other modules, if someone doesnt send any, they pick up the last set value. One way to make it less tightly coupled.

Let me know if you have a concern here.

```js
function myfunction() {
  var year = prompt("enter your birth year");
  Number(year);
  document.getElementById('year').innerHTML = year;
  myage(year);
}

function myage(year = document.getElementById('year').innerHTML) {
  var res;
  res = 2016 - year;
  document.getElementById("age").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<p id="year">
  <h1>YEAR</h1>
</p>
<p id="age">
  <h2>your age is=</h2>
</p>
<button onclick="myfunction()">click to login</button>
```

Comment: yes sir your code is working thank you but please can you tell me that why instead of simply passing year we had to write the whole getElementById statement? @Ayan

Comment: Hey @KaushaniRC, I am glad you asked. This is just a way you can set the default parameter of a function. So, say this myage function is a small part of bigger module.

You dont know from where this module can be called. A module may want to call myage(50), another module say(40). So they might want to show some hardcoded value. In that situation 

this code says - Hey you can send me a parameter. If you dont send any, I take the last set value of $('year').innerHTML.
You can say this to be less tightly coupled.
Mainly useful in large codebases, where you are not sure abt invocations!

Comment: i get your point but i was entering the birth year just once, then why wasn't i getting the output? @Ayan

Comment: Oops! I got a downVote for this. Its just another way I was explaining. Anyways neva mind :'(

Comment: @KaushaniRC you werent sending the parameter, it was coming undefined. So when you were doing arithmetic operations, it was throwing NaN